# Access Localhost from interent via no-ip (behind router+I don't have dedicated ip)

Tags: xampp, dyndns, localtunnel, noip

So I recently tried out ngrok to localtunnel and its good , but I needed static url so I could give someone only once and it would stay that way always! So I found this could be done via no-ip and their client . But the problem is I am behind router(wifi) + my external ip which is shown is my isp''s own ip . Am guessing am using shared internet! So how do I do this now ? can anyone help ?
Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried using a Dynamic DNS service with client updater?

Comment: yeah ! ofcourse ! as i have mentioned i did :( no luck . i don't have dedicated ip btw

Comment: Where did you say you;ve tried this? You don't need a static IP - you just need a client updater that will update your Dynamic DNS server with your current WAN IP - No-Ip and DynDNS will both do the job - unless you have a satellite provider